# What tag should I use for questions about alien conditions?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The Methane-world tech questions left me wondering what tag it ought to have. *planets* is about the planet itself, but what about a tag for alien (unearthly) conditions?

Is an existing tag suitable, or should I create a new one? If the latter, what's a name that would be meaningful?

Answer (score 4):

Very broadly speaking, tags should be used to **categorize the type of domain knowledge that answers need to draw on.**

When adding tags, **ask yourself** the question "is an expert in [abc-xyz](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abc-xyz) the most suitable individual to answer my question?". If the answer to this is a resounding *yes*, then the tag probably makes sense; if the answer is anything less than that, then consider some other tag, or leave it out entirely.

In other words, if you are asking about *the planet itself*, then tagging the question [planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets) makes sense.

If you are asking about *effects on the environment* of some specific condition of the planet, then [environment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environment) is probably more appropriate.

If you are asking about *effects on the society* of that condition of the planet then you could usefully tag the question simply [society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society).

If your question is about *the effects of* commonplace space travel *on* the society *of* a planet, then a tag combination like [society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society) [space-travel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-travel) probably makes sense to categorize the question. Note that such a question is *not* about [planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets) and should not be tagged as such.

If your question is about the effects of a specific level of surface gravity on the development of airships, then a combination like [airship](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airship) [gravity](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravity) probably makes sense, possibly alongside [technological-development](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technological-development) and/or [history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) depending on the specific focus of the question.

*And so on.*

**Just because** the text of a question starts out with, say, "I have a civilization living on a planet where..." this does not necessarily make it a question *about* [planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets). The major exception to this is *if* knowledge about planets (that is, naturally formed celestial objects orbiting a central star) is *specifically useful in answering the actual question being asked*.

Answer (score 2):

I think [planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets) is sufficient.

The wiki says this:

> For questions about planets, how planets interact with the surrounding system and how the large-scale properties of a planet affect its smaller-scale features.

*Large-scale properties* can include atmosphere and how it would affect the *smaller-scale features* of the planet.

If we try to make tags to further categorise planets, we'll end up with Tag Soup™, where users who don't have experience here will find it hard to correctly tag their questions. Not a good thing.

Tags should, in general, be kept *reasonably* generic: [universes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/universes) might not be a viable tag because there are so many possible things a question tagged it might be about, but [planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets) is just about the right level of generic.

Comment: The aspect I'm looking atnis about the environment,  not the planet itself, and not necessarily involving planets! Like in the gas torus; like on a neutron star (*Dragon's Egg*), life *in* a neutron star (*Flux*), life in 26-dimentional manifolds in cyberspace (see Greg Egan), I could go on. Focus on the exotic **conditions**, not one system where they might be found.

Comment: Looking at existing content tagged *environment*, that could be OK, but it has *ecosystems* as a synonym, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @JDługosz in that case, environment is the tag you're looking for. Whether ecosystems is a synonym or not is TBD and I will open a new meta discussion on the point.